# I keep trying to get my Unity 2D player to move, but it looks like I made a mistake in the script that I can't find

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to get my Unity player to move. I develop a 2D Game and I use this Script to try to get move:

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour{

  public float speed;
  private Rigidbody2D rb;
  private Vector2 moveVelocity;

  void Start(){

    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();


      }

  void Update(){
    Vector2.moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"),Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;

    }

  void FixedUpdate(){
    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);



    }

}
```

---

And when i want to open unity, there are always this errors:

Assets\PlayerController.cs(19,13): error CS0117: 'Vector2' does not contain a definition for 'moveInput'

Assets\PlayerController.cs(20,20): error CS0103: The name 'moveInput' does not exist in the current context

I hope i will get some answers! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You put a period between `Vector2` and `moveInput`.

Original:

```
Vector2.moveInput...
```

Fixed:

```
Vector2 moveInput...
```

Calling `Vector2.moveInput` is assuming that the class `Vector2` has a static variable named `moveInput`.